# Django - filter foreign key lookup data

Tags: django, filter

In Django, how do you return filtered foreign key data PLUS the current row's value, if the current row's value
is not in that filtered data?

For example:

**Model** - if I have the following Django (psuedo) models

```
class Record(models.Model):    
    field1
    field2
    ...
    name = models.ForeignKey(Names)

class Names(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField()
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

**Data** - a row in the Names table can be set to active or inactive at any time for example:

```
name           active 
LegacyName1    N 
LegacyName2    N 
ShinyNewName1  Y 
ShinyNewName2  Y 
ShinyNewName3  Y
```

**Forms** - Names should be displayed in a list-box on each form as follows:

add a record -> list active Names

edit a record -> list active Names **PLUS** name of record being edited

display a record -> just display current value, no list box required

However, the catch is when a user edits a Record which has a Name that is no longer active.

They may want to edit other Record details (not necessarily the Name) but they still want to see 
the current Name in the list box along with other possible 'active' options that they could change it to e.g.

The list box entries should display like this

LegacyName1   (current record's value, active ='N')

ShinyNewName1

ShinyNewName2

ShinyNewName3

but 'LegacyName1' does not appear because it is not in the 'active' list of Names, even though it is the Name value for the current record.

### The Django Way?

Django recommends:

- using extra Manager Methods as the preferred way to add “table-level” functionality to your models
- model methods for “row-level” functionality – functions that act on a single instance of a model object.

I've tried the table-level Manager Method and can easily return all 'active' Names via a filter:

```
class NamesManager(models.Manager):        
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(NamesManager, self).get_query_set().filter(active=True)
```

But this knocks the row's existing name out of the list box if it is not active - which is probably to be expected, 
although not what I want.

The row-level approach feels the right way to go since this functionality is specific to a single row for example,
"if my name is not in the list of names, I want to add it anyway" but I can't figure out how/where to fit this in?

A third option might be to use try the Record 'post_init' signal and a fourth option might be perhaps to somehow amend the 'context' 
before it is passed back from the view to the form but both these approaches feels like they might perhaps come under the 'fudged' banner.

Can anyone suggest the preferred Django approach on this? Or maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to show only the active Names when creating a Record, then edit your create form to have the following:

```
class CreateRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Name.objects.filter(active=True))
```

On your EditRecordForm you could introduce a clean method for the name field that verifies that it's still active.

```
class EditRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if not Name.objects.filter(pk=name, active=True.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("The selected name is inactive. Please select a name that is active.")
        return name
```

This also avoids any changes to your ModelManager.